# What is the real focal length of the Lytro Illum

Tags: focal-length, sensor-size

According to Lytro, the Illum Light-field camera will have a 30-250mm **equivalent** focal length with a constant f/2.0 aperture.

1. What is the *actual* focal length of the camera? Or,
2. What is the sensor size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lens is actually 9.5mm to 77.8mm according to [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KAX40LM).  That should make it somewhere around a 1 inch sensor since the crop factor is around 3.

Answer (score 3):

to confirm AJ Henderson's post: the Lightfield Forum says it's a 9.5 - 77.8 mm lens and 1-inch sensor
http://lightfield-forum.com/lytro/lytro-illum-professional-light-field-camera/